# jQuery Post adds parameters to url and works only after second click

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, liferay, velocity

I am using velocity, jQuery and Spring to send values from html form to Java controller and then save them to database.
Unfortunately it works strangely. After first click on button no request is send but instead values from form are added to url as parameters.
After second try and only if I populate form with the same values, post is correctly send to a controller and everything works fine.

Here is code:

HTML

```
#set( $actionURL = $renderResponse.createResourceURL() )
$actionURL.setParameter("action", "save")
#set($captchaUrl = $renderResponse.createResourceURL() + "&p_p_resource_id=captcha")
<form action="$actionURL" novalidate="novalidate">
     ...
      <input type="submit" class="btn-plain-green-big contact-form-send-button" value="Wyślij">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
initSubmit :function(){
    jQuery('#contactFormOut form').unbind('submit');
    jQuery('#contactFormOut form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        //console.log("Submit");
        var postData = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = jQuery(this).attr("action");
        /*if (formURL.indexOf('http:') > -1) {
            //formURL = formURL.replace('http:', 'https:');
        }
        */
        if (jQuery(this).valid()){
            //console.log("Submit - validation ok");
            jQuery(this).attr("action", "#");
            jQuery.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                cache: false,
                success:function(data) 
                {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    if (obj.status == 'OK') {
                        showOkMessage();
                     return false;
                    } else {
                        if(jQuery('#captchaTest').text() != '') {
                            jQuery('#captchaTest').text('');
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) 
                {
                    jQuery.colorbox.close();
                }
            });
          return false;
        } else  {
            //console.log("validation false");
            return false;
        }
     });
}
```

java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "view")
@ResourceMapping
public void save(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException, PortletException, Exception {
    //eveything here works fine and is not important to a problem
}
```

Comment: this is strange.. 
1) why do you unbind "submit"? the following e.preventDefault(); should work fine avoiding default form submit
2) when initSubmit is called? i don't see call or

Comment: It is called on document ready. It is not my code (written by somebody else in company), but I suppose unbiding submit is to prevent calling other submit operation that may be written by somebody else and accidently work with this form. I don't think it's an issue here.